# Wordpress .htaccess/template files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site that I assumed from another company which structurally is a bit different than other ones I've worked on.  I'm primarily a Drupal developer, with enough of a working knowledge of Wordpress to get by.

What the developer who created the site did, is within the themes folder, they created a separate page-whatever-whatever.php file for each page on the site.  Some of the content on the pages within the site have been entered through the CMS system - some are hard coded on to the template file.

Previously, it was hosted on a .NET server - we're on LAMP.

It appears that the pages with the hard coded data aren't being called - so the data the client previously saw is just coming up blank.  The site appears to be ignoring those page-whatever-whatever.php files and using the default template page instead.

My first guess is that it's an htaccess issue?  I just have the generic

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Given the structure they have - is there something else I should be putting in there or changing within the config files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the page-whatever.php templates being called via the wordpress page/post template setting - or are they actual standalone pages entirely?

Comment: By Standalone do you mean completely separated from the WordPress CMS system?  If so - no - I see Wordpress specific tags in those files like getheader() - etc - so it's looking like it's meant to render through WordPress.

Comment: Ahh ok - well if that's the case do they have an associated page within WP? Usually a template only shows when you've assigned it to a page or post. If not, then try resetting the permalink structure, might have gotten itself in a muddle?

Comment: turns out it was a case sensitivity issue.  The permalink is:

domain.com/this-or-that

the PHP file was 

/This-Or-That

renaming it to /this-or-that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess no issue with .htaccess file. The error was in template file. Enable debug in wp-config.php.

By wp_debug was false.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

**Change this to**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Now you can see php error in the template file then debug it.